# How to dynamically disable TextBox in MVC Razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to dynamically disable/enable textbox aftre clicking the checkbox. How can I do it? I'm using this:

```
@{
    object addInput = (Model.AddInput) ? null : new { disabled = "disabled" };

 }

@Html.CheckBoxFor(model=> model.AddInput)

@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Input.Name, addInput)
```

but it works only on start. Clicking the checkbox isn't changing anything. How can do some binding to change disable state automaticaly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This needs to be done in javascript.

```cs
@{
    object addInput = (Model.AddInput) ? null : new { disabled = "disabled" };

 }

@Html.CheckBoxFor(model=> model.AddInput)

@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Input.Name)


<script> 
    $('#AddInput').click(function() {
        var $this = $(this);

        if ($this.is(':checked')) {
            $('#Name').removeAttr("disabled"); 
        } else {
            $('#Name').attr("disabled", "disabled")
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you! It works, I only had to change from #Name to #Input_Name :)

Answer (score 0):

Add jquery action on click on your checkbox and set state appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to enable it for some reason, you can also use the following:

```
      $('#Name').attr("disabled", false);
```

Comment: Question is about disabling - not enabling