# Dynamically disable a TextBoxFor if dropdown value changes to a certain value

Tags: html, razor

Is it possible to dynamically `disable` or make a TextBoxFor `readonly` if dropdown value changes to a certain value **without using helpers or javascript**?

**Razor View**

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.TypeId, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-4">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.TypeId, new SelectList(ViewBag.TypesDDL, "TypeId", "Name"), new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.TypeOthers, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-4">
    @if (Model.TypeId == "Others") {
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TypeOthers, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.TypeOthers, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    }
    </div>
</div>
```

In the code above I used an if statement to display the `TypeOthers TextBoxFor` if the `TypeId DropDownListFor` is equals to `Others` but this doesn't work after load, If I change the dropdown value of `TypeId` to something that's not  `Others` the `TypeOthers TextBoxFor` doesn't appear.

I know this can easily be done by using javascript just like in the code below but I want to know if this can be done just by using `razor`.

```
$("#TypeId").change(function () {
    if (document.getElementById("TypeId").value == "OTHERS") {
        document.getElementById("TypeOthers").disabled = false;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("TypeOthers").disabled = true;
    }
});
```

If I'm not clear enough please just comment.

Comment: May be duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14683420/how-to-dynamically-disable-textbox-in-mvc-razor

Comment: @RaviPatil the accepted answer was in javascript, I want to know if it is possible without javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work try this

```
@{ object displayMode = (Model.Typedof) ? "Others" : new {disabled = "disabled" };
@Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m. TypeOther, "", displayMode)
}
```

Comment: I get the following error 
`Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool'`
`Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'string' and '<anonymous type: string disabled>'`